Preparing text data for raft implementation
I want to use Raft Retrieval Augmented Fine Tuning to build a smart chatbot. My data consists of scraped text from multiple websites. Should I transform it all to QAD format? If so, is there a way to do it automatically?
considering that my dataset is very large and doing it manually would be very difficult?

The RAFT (Retrieval Augmented Fine Tuning) uses a data set consisting of questions, answers, and documents. We could omit answers, but the answers should be in a chai of thought format. The original paper mentions about two types of documents such as

Oracle Documents, one with accurate answers
distractor Document - one which doesn't have context relevant to the answer.

A good primer on preparing data is available in LLAmaIndex repo (https://github.com/run-llama/llama_index/blob/main/llama-index-packs/llama-index-packs-raft-dataset/examples/raft_dataset.ipynb)
